# Html Table Not Rendering in Outlook App/Handheld Devices

Tags: c#, html, outlook

I have a program that sends a report each morning via email. The email displays an html table that shows the most recent backup logs of servers. The program works fine, and the table shows up on a desktop's screen. The problem is viewing it on a phone. We use Outlook as our mail platform.

I originally had the width's set to pixels. I assumed switching them to percentages would be a quick fix; it was not. I've added the presentation role, the border spacing and padding. set the width to auto and a min-width. Nothing has worked and I'm kind of just stuck without any answers that I can find. I am decently new, so I could have easily overlooked something.

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<html>");
        sb.Append("<center>");
        sb.Append("<h1>Latest Backup Dates of Servers</h1>");
        sb.Append("<style> table, th, td {border: 3px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}</ style > ");
        sb.Append("<hr/>");
        sb.Append("<body>");
        sb.Append("<table role:\"presentation\"border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding\"0\" style = \"table-layout:fixed; width:auto; min-width: 100%; \">");
        sb.Append("<colgroup><col style=\"width:10.4%\"><col style=\"width: 20.3%\"><col style=\"width: 23.3%\"><col style=\"width: 14%\"><col style=\"width: 14%\"><col style=\"width: 18%\"></colgroup>");
        sb.Append("<tr>");
        foreach (DataColumn dc in coffeeTable.Columns)
        {
            sb.Append("<th style=\"font-weight:bold;background-color:#0971ce;color:#76bd1d;text-align:center;\">");
            sb.Append(dc.ColumnName.ToString());
            sb.Append("</th>");
        }
        sb.Append("</tr>");

        foreach (DataRow dr in coffeeTable.Rows)
        {
            sb.Append("<tr>");
            foreach (DataColumn dc in coffeeTable.Columns)
            {

                if (dr[dc.ColumnName].Equals("CRITICAL"))
                {
                    sb.Append("<td style=\"background-color: red;\">");
                    sb.Append(dr[dc.ColumnName].ToString());
                    sb.Append("</td>");
                }

                else if (dr[dc.ColumnName].Equals("WARNING"))
                {
                    sb.Append("<td style=\"background-color: yellow;\">");
                    sb.Append(dr[dc.ColumnName].ToString());
                    sb.Append("</td>");
                }

                else if (dr[dc.ColumnName].Equals("UP TO DATE"))
                {
                    sb.Append("<td style=\"background-color: green;\">");
                    sb.Append(dr[dc.ColumnName].ToString());
                    sb.Append("</td>");
                }

                else
                {
                    sb.Append("<td>");
                    sb.Append(dr[dc.ColumnName].ToString());
                    sb.Append("</td>");
                }
            }
            sb.Append("</tr>");
        }


        sb.Append("</table>");
        sb.Append("</body>");
        sb.Append("</center>");
        sb.Append("</html>");
```

[Phone Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCGMG.jpg)
[Desktop Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BbIe.jpg)

Comment: You could always look into [ghost tables](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-email-using-ghost-tables--cms-32551)

Comment: Also, unsure how finicky rendering on mobile is with syntax, but I'm guessing: **very**. Add a space in here to become: `sb.Append("<table role:\"presentation\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding\"0\" style = \"table-layout:fixed; width:auto; min-width: 100%; \">");`

Comment: The ghost tables worked, thanks!